# Why design the callback parameter as a Module?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

According to the documentation for [EventMachine.watch_file](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.watch_file) the `handler` argument has to be a Module (or a class inheriting from `EventMachine::FileWatch`). Why is it designed this way? For me a block (or Proc) argument would be more natural and flexible (since it allows to use local variables via closure)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are not super clear, but you can also supply a sub-class of `FileWatch`.  That would let you use locals more easily.

It takes either a module with the needed methods, or a class with the needed methods **AND** it must be a sub-class of the desired class.

Take a [look at the code](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1282), specifically, the [klass_from_handler](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1527) method.

Comment: Thanks, it works simply by passing the arguments to constructor!